# List within Dictionary - int object is not iterable

Tags: python

I'm working on a strange discord bot for my friends and I, and one part of the code involves creating a dictionary, which can hold lists containing the name of an item, and it's cost.

For reference, a dict named "userShop" holds stuff like so:

`{'DiscordName#0000': [23, 'test item']}`, where the discord name is self-explanatory, the int is the cost of the item, and the string is the name of the item.

In order to "purchase" the item, the user types in the command `!buyitem <cost> <name>`, which starts the following snippit of code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def buyitem(ctx, buyFrom: str, *, item: str):
    userName = str(ctx.message.author)
    for itemName, cost in userShop[buyFrom]:
        if itemName == item:
            #blah blah blah
```

Which returns the error

`for itemName, cost in userShop[buyFrom]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

What can I do to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: `userShop` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: The error is very suggestive: `userShop[buyFrom]` returns an `integer` and not a `list` as you expect..

Comment: Did you try to inspect(print) the data at the point of the exception?  Work *backwards* from there.

Comment: When adding in `print(userShop[buyFrom])` before anything else happens in the function, a list is printed out (`[23, 'test item']`, to be exact)

Comment: in what way? `{'DiscordName#0000': [23, 'test item']}` shows that the dict value is a list of two items, right? (not trying to sound snarky, genuine question <33)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `userShop[buyFrom]` is a list like this `[23, 'test item']` you can not directly assign the two values in two variables using `in`.

You should use:

```
itemName = userShop[buyFrom][0]
cost = userShop[buyFrom][1]
if itemName == item:
    #blah blah blah
```